# jquery not work on all php records

Tags: php, jquery, split

my CMS uploads my image and store its as

```
{"name":"download(2).jpg","filename":"download(2).jpg"}
```

I want to extract the filename only. i tried the following using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var str = $('#url').html();
var n = str.split('":"');
var t = n[1].split('","');  

$("#imagephoto").attr('src', "../content/" + t[0]);

});
```

It works on the first Record but the rest does not work. I am not sure how to do it with php. I gave it a try as:

```
  <img id="imagephoto" src=" <?php 
  function GetBetween ( $row_Recordset1['data'] ,'":"','","'){
  $r = explode('":"', $row_Recordset1['data']);
  if (isset($r[1])){
      $r = explode('","', $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
 }
 return '';
} ?>
"/>
```

But I get a syntax error on the 2nd line - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

How can I get this correct!!

Comment: check this out use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: erm, `{"name":"download(2).jpg","filename":"download(2).jpg"}` is JSON, you might want to check out php's `json_decode` and javascripts `JSON.parse`

Comment: Would be deply gald if you leave an answer using mixed json_decode

Answer (score 0):

Worked Finally

```
      <img id="imagephoto" src="../content/<?php

      $json = $row_Recordset1['data'];

      $obj = json_decode($json);
      print $obj->{'name'};

      ?>"/>
```